# Conditional expression for if variable present in model

Tags: r

What I want to do is to make a condition for if there is a certain variable in linear model

Example. If there is a B in a linear model

```
model <- lm(Y ~ A + B + C)
```

I want to do something. I have used the summary function before to refer to R-squared.

```
summary(model)$r.squared
```

Probably I am looking for something like this

```
if (B %in% summary(model)$xxx)
```

or

```
if (B %in% summary(model)[xxx])
```

But I can't find xxx. Please help =)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if ("B" %in% all.vars(formula(model))) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
if ("B" %in% names(coef(model)))
```

Comment: @Aniko Good catch. My solution with `variable.names` failed with factors too.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
if ("B" %in% variable.names(model)) ...
```

Comment: variable.names was just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Roman In case of factor variable you get name in form "variable-level" (as Aniko states in a comment to [nico answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429361/conditional-expression-for-if-variable-present-in-model/4429752#4429752)).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to grab the model terms from the fitted model and interrogate the `term.labels` attribute. Using some dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(100), A = rnorm(100), B = rnorm(100), C = rnorm(100))
model <- lm(Y ~ A + B + C, data = DF)
```

The terms object contains the labels in an attribute:

```
> attr(terms(model), "term.labels")
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

So check if `"B"` is in that set of labels:

```
> if("B" %in% attr(terms(model), "term.labels")) {
+     summary(model)$r.squared
+ }
[1] 0.003134009
```

Answer (score 0):

A (somewhat inelegant) possible solutions would be:

```
length(grep("\\bB\\b",formula(model))) > 0
```

where `\\b` matches the word boundary and `B` is the variable name you're looking for.

Comment: @Roman Equivalent of aix expression is `"^[[:space:]]*B[[:space:]]*$"`. But in this particular case `"^B"` will work too (and more safely `"^B$"`